# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html even though my index.html is in a "templates" folder

Tags: python, html, flask, directory, jinja2

I'm learning how to code using python's flask but I can't seem to sucessfully run my server. For some reason, I keep getting Template not found but I do have my index.html in my templates folder just like flask wants me to. I've attached an image showing the folder. [folders and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDgh9.png)

I have tried using the "app = Flask("Web Translator", template_folder='new folder name')" and changing the folder name and replacing the template_folder="new folder name" but it does not work. When I try to run my server it shows this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK3gk.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should create the Flask Object

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='new folder name')
```

The `__name__` variable is a special variable that represents the name of the current module. When you run a Python script directly, the `__name__` variable is set to `__main__`.

In the context of `Flask`, the `__name__` variable is used to determine the root path of the application. It helps Flask locate the root directory of the project and find other files and folders relative to that path.

---

Now after looking at your code, the page you want to render is in `\new folder name\template\index.html`
then your code shall work fine.

```
return render_template('templates/index.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have `return render_template('templates/index.html')`. Flask will look for a folder called 'templates' within the default template folder.

You should simply have it as `return render_template('index.html')`

Also, conventionally, you do `app = Flask(__name__)`. See [this](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/why-do-we-pass-name-to-the-flask-class) for an explanation on why

Comment: Thank you! After changing to Flask(__name__)my server started working!